# Kafka is marking the coordinator dead when autoscaling is on

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

We run a Kubernetes cluster with Kafka 0.10.2. In the cluster we have a replica set of 10 replicas running one of our services, which consume from one topic as one consumer-group.

Lately we turned on the autoscaling feature for this replica-set, so it can increase or decrease the number of pods, based on its CPU consumption.

Soon after this feature was enabled we started to see lags in our Kafka queue. I looked at the log and saw the consumer is marking the coordinator dead very often (almost every 5 minutes) and the reconnect to the same coordinator few seconds later.

I also saw frequently in the logs:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 
This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. 
You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

It takes a few seconds to process a message (normally) and we never had this kind of issues before. I assume the problem relates to a bad partition assignment but I can't pinpoint the problem.

If we kill pod that got "stuck" Kafka reassign the partition to another pod and it get stuck as well, but if we scale down the replica-set to 0 and then scale it up the messages are being consumed quickly!

Relevant consumer configurations:

```
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
session.timeout.ms = 10000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, do you have any `readinessProbe` set on your autoscaling pods? Also, does this behaviour occur only when scaling down?

Comment: 1. Yes we have a basic readinessProbe, based on Spring /info endpoint. 2. It happens when we scale up as well...

Comment: And what is the initial delay until your pod is considered ready? Also, what is the value of `request.timeout.ms`?

Comment: initial delay is 2 minutes, request.timeout.ms = 305000

Comment: And how many partitions do you have for the topic? Is it possible that your app scaled where consumers > partitions and for that remained idle?

Comment: Nope.. we have around 3-4 partition per consumer

Comment: What version of spring-cloud-stream and spring-kafka?

Comment: spring.cloud.version: 1.1.0, spring-kafka: 1.1.1. I just read this article: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/ but couldn't tell what version to use... The broker's version is 0.10.2.1 and spring boot version is 1.5. @GaryRussell any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is the problem but Spring kafka 1.1.x had a very complicated threading model (required by the 0.9 clients). For long-running listeners we had to pause/resume the consumer thread; I saw some issues with early kafka versions where the resume didn't always work.

KIP-62 allowed us to greatly simplify the threading model.

This was incorporated into the 1.3.x line.

I would suggest upgrading to at least [cloud-stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) Ditmars, which uses spring-kafka 1.3.x. The current 1.3.x version is 1.3.8.